# find tags from database with some similarity between them

Tags: php, database, tags

I want to find tag (or say main tag) from available tags in database with

> TABLE: tags => COLUMNS: tag_id,customer_id,tag

- how to find of same tags from column 'tag'
- and how to give probability (or weight) to all those tags to find main tag.

I work in php and designing a web site that contain search method for tags and user add tags as any form like two similar #awesome and #awsm .

Answer (score 0):

You can find tags from database as per user type

```
$tags = $_POST['tag'];

$sql = 'SELECT * from tag WHERE tag = '%".$tags."%' ';
```

Comment: no, actually i want to find out meaning of tags in the way of its similarity. how they are similar to each other

Answer (score 0):

Depends what do you mean by similarity. If simply `abc` is similar to `123abc_ok` then there is no problem. If you want `abc` to be similar to `adbc` then you are in worse position as you must write logic for PHP to understand your point of view to similarity.

For simple way there is sql query:

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM tag WHERE tag LIKE '%".$tag."%'";`

This will select every record, where `tag` field contains `$tag` value.

Comment: here i mentioned #awsm and #awesome, both has similar meaning. so i want to find out these type of tags with similar meaning with its probability.(in terms of how many letter matches in tags or another best algorithm if available)

Comment: Last time I checked, computers can't understand meanings of words. And those tags are no way similar to each other from a computer's point of view.

Comment: if there is an algorithm to find out similarity at certain point

Comment: Then you need to write your own. But to do this you'd need to select all tags from database and run your algorithm for every one of them comparising it to input. I'm pretty sure no serious website does that. I think it's probable that they have ready sets of similar strings. A set like for example `Google -> [gogle,goglee,gogl,googl,goggle]` or something like that.